# Wordpress FrontEnd Ajax return 0 using Theme

Tags: ajax, wordpress, themes, frontend

Hi I know this has been asked a few times but I have been through every answer and tried them all with no luck.

I am trying to use Ajax in a Wordpress front end page, I have security in the page to ensure the user is logged in before they can view this page too.

No matter what code i enter my ajax call always returns 0.

```
function ajaxfoodlookup()
{
    echo "ajax fired";
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_ajaxfoodlookup','ajaxfoodlookup');
add_action('wp_ajax_ajaxfoodlookup','ajaxfoodlookup');
```

This is what I have in my functions.php (i have also tried exit(); and die($results) where $results = 'ajax fired'; nothing seems to work.

This is what I have in the page to call the ajax;

```
jQuery.ajax({
      url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { action:'ajaxfoodlookup'},
      success: function (data) { alert(data);}
    });
```

The only thing that I have different to the other questions/answers on here is that I am using a bought Theme which does have some code added, is that theme able to hijack my ajax calls?  I thought wordpress would execute the ajax call depending on the 'action' in the data supplied?

Please help its driving me crazy?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Official WordPress recommendation is to use the `ajaxurl` variable instead of hard coded one. Insert this before your JS code and change the `url` of your `jQuery.ajax` to use `ajaxurl`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';
</script>
```

You can also use [wp_localize_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to define the `ajaxurl`